# how to push a git commit without creating a branch?

Tags: git, github

i would like to get off a branch (e.g. `git switch HEAD -d`), make a commit, and push it to a remote (e.g. github) without creating a branch there.

use case is that sometimes i want to ask someone "is this what you mean?" and link to a commit, but i don't want github to prompt me to create a PR, or for this garbage to show up everywhere you can list branches.

how do i push a git commit without creating a branch?

Comment: I don't think you can have an orphan commit out there with no label, but a [`tag`](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Tagging) may be sufficient to your requirements of allowing you to point to a commit or tag without polluting the branches namespace?

Comment: @AlexanderNied i appreciate that suggestion! i would prefer to not pollute the tag namespace as well. maybe as a workaround i can simply make an alias or shell script that pushes up the branch/tag and deletes it right after it's pushed

Comment: I would just create branch. You can always delete it when you're done (`git push --delete origin my-example-branch`).

Comment: @schpet - unfortunately, I'm relatively certain as soon as the tag was deleted the commit would disappear with it-- I don't think you can have dangling commits.  That said, it would be easy enough to test manually before writing a script.

Comment: You can try to push to a named ref which isn't a branch (`refs/heads/...`) or a tag (`refs/tags/...`) : `git push origin my_commit:refs/snapshots/xyz`. I don't know what rules are enforced by GitHub on the accepted names, though.

Comment: One solution is to add your colleague's repo as a remote to your own. This requires setting up SSH or HTTPS on their machine, though.

Comment: You could also push the branch to GitHub and delete it after your colleague pulls it down.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK you have to create a ref to it. Fortunately you can probably get close enough for practical purposes:

1. Create a local branch with the commit.
2. Push it.
3. Immediately delete the remote branch.
4. Provide the full 40 char hash to the user to fetch: `git fetch origin <full-hash>`

Note the only reason you can even do the above steps is because garbage collection is not instantaneous and enables orphaned commits to stick around for a while. In the case of GitHub and many other tools, it may even stick around *forever* without further intervention. In this case the lifetime of the branch only needs to be for a few seconds just so you can push "something".

**Side Note:** you can skip step 1 if you wish and push directly to a branch name on the remote only:

```
# push commit <hash> to remote branch
git push origin <hash>:some-temp-branch-name
# delete remote branch
git push -d origin some-temp-branch-name
```